# how to use initiate function for a cart in Django?

Tags: django-models

I'm learning Django and I'm trying to make a Cart, which the customer can get and item and add it in his/her order row and then the order will be submitted. so my teacher said use def initiate(customer), and I don't understand how to use it. Can someone please explain it to me? Thank you. 
here is the code I'm working on it:

```
User = get_user_model()

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=Product, related_name="User")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.TextField()
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=20000)

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        self.save()

    def spend(self, amount):
        if amount > self.balance:
            raise ValueError
        self.balance -= amount
        self.save()


class OrderRow(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()


class Order(models.Model):
    # Status values. DO NOT EDIT
    STATUS_SHOPPING = 1
    STATUS_SUBMITTED = 2
    STATUS_CANCELED = 3
    STATUS_SENT = 4



    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    order_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    total_price = Sum(F('amount') * F('product__price'))
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=status_choices)

    @staticmethod
    def initiate(customer):
        Order.initiate(User)

    def add_product(self, product, amount):
        Order.status = 1
        OrderRow.product = Product.objects.get(id=product.id)
        print(product.id)
        if OrderRow.objects.filter(product=product).exists():
            preexisting_order = OrderRow.objects.get(product=product, order=self)
            preexisting_order.amount += 1
            preexisting_order.save()
        else:
            new_order = OrderRow.objects.create(
                product=product,
                cart=self,
                amount=1,

            )
            new_order.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably supposed to create a new Order associated with this `customer`. Something along the following lines:

```
@classmethod
def initiate(cls, customer):
    return cls.objects.create(customer=customer, status=cls.STATUS_SHOPPING)
```

There are some other issues with your code. You cannot use `SET_NULL` if the fk is not nullable:

```
customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=true)
```

There should not be multiple products per row:

```
class OrderRow(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)  # not many2many!
    # ...
```

Also, your `add_product` needs quite some fixing:

```
def add_product(self, product, amount):
    self.status = self.STATUS_SHOPPING  # the instance is self + use your descriptive variables
    print(product.id)
    # filter only rows in the current order!
    if self.orderrow_set.filter(product=product).exists():
        # fix naming: this is a row, not an order
        preexisting_order_row = self.orderrow_set.get(product=product)
        preexisting_order_row.amount += amount  # why +1, you are adding amount
        preexisting_order_row.save()
    else:
        new_order_row = OrderRow.objects.create(
            product=product,
            order=self,
            amount=amount,
        )  # create saves already
```

Comment: Thank you, so initiate needs to arguments? I'm still learning, sorry if I ask many questions but why we use cls? about the product in OrderRow I only should work on the amount then?

Comment: You can keep it a staticmethod and use `Order.objects.create...`. But a classmethod is more in the spirit of object-oriented-programming as the method will work on sub-classes. Very often it will make no difference. And yes, the OrderRow model **is** itself the many2many mapping from order to product. There can be many rows in an order but each of them represents one product of a certain quantity.

Comment: Thank you, can I bother you by asking another question here? or you think I should post a new question? it's about to define submit in model.py.